# sub-string text with a running number

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, substring

This should be very simple and short, but i cannot think of a good and short way of doing this: 
I have a string for instance:

> 'How many roads must a man walk down Before you call him a man? How
>   many seas must a white dove sail Before she sleeps in the sand? Yes,
>   and how many times must the cannon balls fly Before they're forever
>   banned?'

and I want to substring a word say "how" with a running number so i get:

> '[1] many roads must a man walk down Before you call him a man? [2]
>   many seas must a white dove sail Before she sleeps in the sand? Yes,
>   and [3] many times must the cannon balls fly Before they're forever
>   banned?'

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilise `itertools.count` and a function as the replacement argument, eg:

```
import re
from itertools import count

text = '''How many roads must a man walk down Before you call him a man? How many seas must a white dove sail Before she sleeps in the sand? Yes, and how many times must the cannon balls fly Before they're forever banned?'''
result = re.sub(r'(?i)\bhow\b', lambda m, c=count(1): '[{}]'.format(next(c)), text)
# [1] many roads must a man walk down Before you call him a man? [2] many seas must a white dove sail Before she sleeps in the sand? Yes, and [3] many times must the cannon balls fly Before they're forever banned?
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with a replacement function. The function will look up how often that word has been seen in a dictionary and return an according number.

```
counts = collections.defaultdict(int)
def subst_count(match):
    word = match.group().lower()
    counts[word] += 1
    return "[%d]" % counts[word]
```

Example:

```
>>> text = "How many ...? How many ...? Yes, and how many ...?"
>>> re.sub(r"\bhow\b", subst_count, text, flags=re.I)
'[1] many ...? [2] many ...? Yes, and [3] many ...?'
```

Note: This uses *different* counts for each word to replace (in case you use a regex that matched more than one word), but will *not* reset counts between calls to `re.sub`.

Comment: This is the best solution. Really nice use of function as an argument for the parameter `string` in `re.sub`. And using `\b` to find only the occurences of "how" but not "somehow", "however" or similar deserves a double vote. Unfortunately I can upvote only once.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it with `re.sub` with a replacement function. But rather than using a global object to keep track of the count this code uses a function attribute.

```
import re

def count_replace():
    def replace(m):
        replace.count += 1
        return '[%d]' % replace.count
    replace.count = 0
    return replace

src = '''How many roads must a man walk down Before you call him a man? How many seas must a white dove sail Before she sleeps in the sand? Yes, and how many times must the cannon balls fly Before they're forever banned?'''

pat = re.compile('how', re.I)

print(pat.sub(count_replace(), src))
```

**output**

> [1] many roads must a man walk down Before you call him a man? [2]
>   many seas must a white dove sail Before she sleeps in the sand? Yes,
>   and [3] many times must the cannon balls fly Before they're forever
>   banned?

If you need to *only* replace complete words and not partial words, then you'll need a smarter regex, eg `r"\bhow\b"`.

Comment: Yes, that's better in case you want to replace counts in more than one string (and reset counts in between). Might add `\b` to regex, to avoid replacing "how" as part of other words, though.

Comment: Thanks, @tobias_k. Also, `count_replace` can easily be modified to accept an arg to initialise `replace.count` to a non-zero value.

Comment: This is great too. Is `replace` within `count_replace` a closure?

Comment: @cezar: Yes, `replace` is a closure. This makes it easy to create multiple independent replace functions, and it also streamlines the process of attaching the `.count` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test = 'How many roads must a man walk down Before you call him a man? How many seas must a white dove sail Before she sleeps in the sand? Yes, and how many times must the cannon balls fly Before theyre forever banned?'

i = 0

while("How" in Test):
    new = "["+str(i)+"]"
    Test = Test.replace("How",new,i)
    i=i+1


print Test
```

**Output**

```
[1] many roads must a man walk down Before you call him a man? [2] many seas   must a white dove sail Before she sleeps in the sand? Yes, and how many times must the cannon balls fly Before theyre forever banned?
```

Comment: For me, this runs into an infinite loop, because you test for `How` but replace `how`. The idea is good, but you have to find a way to handle different cases (that's why I used regex)

Comment: Maybe start with replacing all `How` by `how`, but this will still have the problem of replacing `how` in other words, too.

Comment: But you did not fix the problem (just another problem I did not notice at first). I don't see how you got that output. The program does not seem to terminate at all.

Comment: @tobias_k That error is because in validation in am using "How" and in replacement.I replaced with "how"

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you in my very first comment. However, your script still does not work, as it does not replace lowercase `"how"`. Also, it will replace `"how"` in `"somehow"` and similar.

Comment: @tobias_k we can use " how " to avoid "somehow" but it will fail if "how" is starting element

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I wanted to see if I could solve this using recursion, and this is what I got:

```
def count_replace(s, to_replace, leng=0, count=1, replaced=[]):
    if s.find(' ') == -1:
        replaced.append(s)
        return ' '.join(replaced)
    else:
        if s[0:s.find(' ')].lower() == to_replace.lower():
            replaced.append('[%d]' % count)
            count += 1
            leng = len(to_replace)
        else:
            replaced.append(s[0:s.find(' ')])
            leng = s.find(' ')
        return count_replace(s[leng + 1:], to_replace, leng, count, replaced)
```

It goes without saying that I wouldn't recommend this as it's ridiculously inefficient on top of the fact that it's also overly complicated, but I thought I'd share it anyway!